# How to confine a plot inside a frame?

Tags: pstricks, framed

I'm using `\listplot` to plot a datafile I made. The section of the plot I am interested in ranges from `y=-40` to `y=60` but there is a peak in this plot which goes way above `y=100`. I don't want to show this peak in its entirety because it would make the section I'm concerned with too small, but I want it plotted until `y=60` because it is important to know it is there. My graph is framed but this peak sticks out of the frame so I would like to know if there is a way to 'erase' anything coming out of a region delimited by a frame.

Comment: Probably use  the environment `pspicture*`  instead of `pspicture`: it will crop the plot to what's inside the pspicture box.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.data}
0 -40  1 -30  2 -20  3 0  4 100 5 10 6 30 7 60  
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\psset{yunit=0.1}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-45)(7.5,65)
\readdata{\data}{test.data}
\psaxes[ticksize=0 5pt,Dy=10]{->}(0,0)(0,-40)(7,60)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\listplot[plotYMax=60]{\data}
\listplot[linecolor=red]{\data}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]